# IF ELSE in Java Script

Tags: javascript, if-statement

for some reason the following code is not coloring as should. What did I do wrong?

```
if (Group == 'Customer') {
    if (Status != 'Agreement') {
        cell.css('color', 'blue');
    }

} else if (Group == 'Non-customer') {
     if (Status == null) {
         cell.css('color', 'green');
     } else {
         if (Status != 'Agreement') {
             cell.css('color', 'yellow');
         } else if (Status == 'Not declared') {
             cell.css('color', 'purple');
         }                
     }
}
```

Comment: You have a mix of using and not using braces.  I would recommend adding braces in such complex if/else logic so you can tell whether things are where they should be.  Only you know where those should be.

Comment: What do you mean 'is not coloring as should'?

Comment: Something with semicolon insertion? The lack of braces in a language that tends to put `;` in random places scares me.

Comment: U miss brackets what i see.. Check these

Comment: I have data of a Group `Non-customer` and Status `Agreement` - it's not colored purple.

Comment: Interesting statement though, you will never reach the last `if`, `'Not declared'` is also `!= 'Agreement'`. You should just read some JS book I guess.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* You currently have people arguing over what the code is doing. Please [edit] your question to include enough code to duplicate your issue so others can see what is happening.

Comment: @migg: Quite true. At first I thought you were mistaken, but that `!= 'Agreement'` will kick in, sure enough. I wonder if that's the answer to the question? :-) (We don't know, since "not coloring as it should" tells us nothing about what it should do.)

Comment: You've really made a mess here with your formatting and I think it's making it impossible for most of us (and you) to follow. Placing `if` on a separate line after `else` for an `else if` is just super confusing (and I'm surprised it even runs like that). Additionally your variable naming violates the standard JS style-guide. Have a look at this: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/es5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (Group == 'Customer') {
  if(Status != 'Agreement') {
    cell.css ('color', 'blue');
  }
}

else if (Group == 'Non-customer') {
  if (Staus == null) {
    cell.css ('color', 'green');
  }
  else if (Status != 'Agreement') {
    cell.css ('color', 'yellow');
  }  
  else if (Status != 'Not declared') {
    cell.css ('color', 'purple');
  }
}
```